# About the derivation of the Hamilton-Jacobi equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

It is an old question for me. In Goldstein's book, the H-J equation is derived in this way. We want to find a generating function $F(q,P,t)$ such that the transformed Hamiltonian vanishes identically,
\begin{equation}
H(q, p, t) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}= 0.\tag{10-2}
\end{equation}

Here the generating function induces the following canonical transform

\begin{equation}
p = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q}, \qquad Q = \frac{\partial F}{\partial P}.
\end{equation}

The H-J equation is obtained by substituting the first transform equation $p = \frac{\partial F}{\partial q}$ into the equation above. The H-J equation is then written in this form:

\begin{equation}
H(q, \frac{\partial F}{\partial q} ,t) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=0.\tag{10-3}
\end{equation}

The point is that, in this equation, $F$ is understood as a function of $q$ and $t$, no longer as a function of $q$, $P$, $t$.

Is this okay?

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): What do you mean? Hamilton's principal function $F\equiv S$ depends on $q$, $P\equiv \alpha$, and $t$.

Comment: I just feel that, H-J equation is not derived straightforwardly. There is something justified a posteriori.